# Having problem handling errors in react-redux white attempting to SignUp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image]Here i have my component code for SignIng Up user and check for Error. At first error is null.

```
      let error = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.error);

      const checkErrorLoading = () => {        
        console.log("If error found");  //At first it gives null, but on backend there is error
        toast.error(error);
        console.log(loading, error);
      };

      const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        if (isSignup) {
          dispatch(signup(form, history));
          checkErrorLoading();
        } else {
          dispatch(signin(form, history));
          checkErrorLoading();
        }
      };
```

Now at my singupForm, i provide wrong input or wrong data. The backend gives me error that is completely fine.

***ISSUE* => But when i click on Login button. At first attempt it does not provide any error message. After second attempt it works fine, but not at first attempt. At first attempt it gives me Error value NULL while there is still an error**

Here is my action.

```
    export const signup = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
      try {
        const res = await api.signUp(formData);
        dispatch({ type: authConstants.AUTH_REQUEST });
        if (res.status === 200) {
          const { data } = res;
          console.log(data);
          dispatch({
            type: authConstants.AUTH_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
          });
        }
        console.log(res.status);
        history.push("/");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        dispatch({
          type: authConstants.AUTH_FAILURE,
          payload: error.response.data.error,
        });
      }
    };
```

and than reducer.

```
    const initialState = {
      authData: null,
      error: null,
      loading: false,
    };

    const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case authConstants.AUTH_REQUEST:
          return { ...state, loading: true, error: null };

        case authConstants.AUTH_SUCCESS:
          localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify({ ...action?.payload }));
          return { ...state, authData: action?.data, loading: false, error: null };

        case authConstants.AUTH_FAILURE:
          console.log(action.payload);
          return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `useEffect` instead of local function (`checkErrorLoading` ) for such cases:

```
    useEffect(() => {        
      console.log("If error found");
      toast.error(error);
      console.log(loading, error);
    },[error]);
```

Currently what you doing is creating local function that closures `error` variable, which initially is `null` + state is updated asynchronously, so you cannot execute function right after dispatching (even if variable wouldn't be closured, you will not have fresh state there)

Comment: Thanks for that, it just save me :).